# Степень дифференцирования при союзах "а также" и "и"

Tags: синтаксис, союзы, однородные-члены, определения

*Научные статьи, курсовые, а также рефераты по схожей
тематике.*

*Научные статьи, курсовые и рефераты по схожей
тематике.*

Верно ли, что союз "а также", присоединяет однородный член предложения, который имеет добавочный характер, поэтому сильнее дифференциирует, отделяет его от других, чем союз "и", и при наличии зависимых слов при последнем однородном члене эти слова относятся исключительно к нему, тогда как при союзе "и" они относятся ко всем однородным членам? Или всё решается исходя из смысла и возможно отнесение зависимых слов и только к последнему, и ко всем однородным членам и при том, и при другом союзе?

Comment: Нет смысла  обсуждать отдельно  эти словосочетания, приведите полный текст предложений.  Тогда можно будет судить как о функциях союзов И, А ТАКЖЕ, так  и о корректности данного высказывания в целом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, руководствоваться всегда нужно смыслом. Союз а также как раз и говорит о смысле, о присоединительном характере:

*Научные статьи, курсовые, а также рефераты по схожей тематике.* Рефераты по тематике, схожей с научными статьями и курсовыми. Иначе зачем же рефераты выделили?

Научные статьи, курсовые и рефераты по схожей тематике. Здесь возможно отнесение "по схожей тематике" и ко всем однородным членам, и к последнему.

Comment: А если по контексту ясно, что научные статьи, курсовые и рефераты написаны по тематике, схожей с тематикой чего-то другого, то использование союза "а также" будет корректно? Или тогда нет основания для отделения?

Comment: По-моему, тогда лучше использовать союз И.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант примера с союзом «и» - правильный. Применение союза «а также» не оправдано, поскольку нет очевидного повода для отделения понятия «научная статья» от понятия «реферат». Союз «а также» будет к месту в такой, например, фразе:
«Научные статьи, курсовые работы и рефераты, а также теле и радиопередачи по схожей тематике.»

А ТАКЖЕ (союз)

Употребляется при присоединении однородного члена предложения ( который - являясь добавочным - отграничивается от другого или от ряда других однородных членов ) , соответствуя по значению сл.: и.

Большой современный толковый словарь русского языка. 2012

«Но все ж березы, липы, клены, 
Акаций запыленных ряд, 
А также галки и вороны
И глаз, и ухо веселят. 
[Ф. К. Сологуб. «Сплетают тени на песочке...» (1887.06.14)]»

«При этом он предварительно оценил, что благоприятная политическая обстановка для и.о. губернаторов складывается в 9 регионах — Воронежской, Челябинской, Волгоградской, Курганской, Тюменской, Самарской, Курской областях, а также в Удмуртии и Республике Коми. [Анастасия Кашеварова, Мария Самохвалова. Кремль проведет мониторинг выборов // Известия, 2014.07.03]»

Союз "а также" присоединяет предметы/понятия, отграничивая  (сортируя) их по какому либо признаку. 
Союзом «и» можно объединить и противопоставить «они сошлись вода и камень, стихи и проза, лед и пламень». 
Удачных попыток противопоставления с использованием союза «а также» встречать не доводилось. 
Есть пример неудачной попытки:

«Определение Верховного Суда РФ от 13.01.2003 № 14−Г02−35


3) в третью очередь — объектов недвижимого имущества, а также сырья и материалов, станков, оборудования, других основных средств, предназначенных для непосредственного участия в производстве.

Из изложенной нормы следует, что объекты недвижимости вне зависимости от их участия в основном производстве относятся к третьей очереди. 
Суд же в результате ошибочного толкования отнес ПТК к первой очереди как имущество, непосредственно не участвующее в основном производстве.

Между тем при перечислении имущества третьей очереди законодатель использовал союз «а также», распространяя тем самым непосредственное участие в производстве лишь на сырье, материалы, станки, оборудование, другие основные средства, но не на объекты недвижимости.»

Comment: Вариант примера с союзом «и»  правильный? Но там же нет однозначной семантики: зависимые слова можно отнести и к ряду, и к последнему члену. Это стилистическая неточность, которую следует избегать. А чтобы редактировать предложение, требуется его полный текст.

Comment: Конечно же Вы правы, Jasmin. Двойственность толкования фраз в вопросе Василия - налицо. Но, как мне кажется,  приведенные в ответе примеры (в т.ч., последний) помогут ему  прийти к такому же выводу самостоятельно.